# How To Retrieve data from Bundle data in target activity Passed from source activity

Tags: android

first activity:

```
    String s="create_newfile";
    Intent i = new Intent("com.monster.android.Showfile");
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("task",s);
    i.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(i);
```

second activity:

```
    Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();

    String s = extras.getString("task");

    if (extras!=null && s=="create_newfile")
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.edit);
    }
```

its showing error!!!

Comment: next time: please use shorter title and be a little more specific of what type of error you get. triad is right, comparing strings with operator == fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "==" compares reference values bit by bit not the value referenced by that reference.
2. "equals()" compares by value.Though equals method of base "Object" class is using "==" but it is overridden in most of class to compare value.

So Change into this :

```
if (extras!=null && s.equals("create_newfile")
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.edit);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't compare Strings with `==`.

You need to compare Strings using `string1.equals("some_other_string")`, so in your case, `s.equals("create_newfile")`

Comment: and you should do the null check before extras.getString("task")

Comment: or check "task".equals(extras.getString("task"))